# String substitution in Views Contextual filter parameter?

Tags: views, entities, hooks, routes, 9

In Drupal 9, I have a View called **News**.

The View is displayed at the following path:

`/news`

I can edit it at the following path:

`/admin/structure/views/view/news/edit`

It has the following Contextual filter:

`Content datasource: Content type`

The contextual filter values are provided by the URL.

**When the filter value is *NOT* in the URL:** `Provide default value`

**Type:** `Fixed`

**Fixed value:** `all`

**Exception value:** `all`

If this value is received, the filter will be ignored; i.e, "all values"

This works well for content types like `article` and `blog_post`.

When the View is displayed for the path `/news/article`, the contextual filter shows only Content type `article`.

When the View is displayed for the path `/news/blog_post`, the contextual filter shows only Content type `blog_post`.

So far, so good.

Now, the client has a custom content type called "Youtube Video" with machine name `youtube_video`.

When this View is displayed for the path `/news/youtube_video`. the contextual filter shows only Content type `youtube_video`.

But the client wants the path to be `/news/video`.

What are my options?

Some constraints:

- The client *definitely* wants the path to be `/news/video`, and not something like `/news?type=video`.
- I don't think that it's trivial to match `/news/foo` and substitute `bar` for `foo` as the input for a contextual filter.
- I know how to use positional parameters in a route, but I don't think I can easily override the route for just `/news/foo` while preserving the contextual filter as it is for the other content types.

Some flexibility:

- The Drupal 9 site is brand new, and I'm about to migrate the content from Drupal 7 via Migrate API, so it's *possible* to change the machine name of the `youtube_video` content type to `video` during the migration. Then this View would work without modification. (The problem would be figuring out everything else that references the machine name `youtube_video` and changing that to `video` also -- potentially a lot of effort.)
- It may be possible to alter the query parameters conditionally using `hook_views_pre_view()` or `hook_views_query_alter()`, but I only want to do this if a specific parameter is matched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would `hook_views_pre_view()` do the trick?

```
function hook_views_pre_view(ViewExecutable $view, $display_id, array &$args) {
  if ($view->id() == 'my_view' &&
    $display_id == 'my_display' &&
    $args[0] == 'news' &&
    $args[1] == 'video') {
    $args[1] = 'youtube_video';
  }
}
```

Replace `my_view` and `my_display` with the appropriate values.

Comment: Thanks @uberhacker. I accepted your answer, which basically set me on the right path.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my first working proof-of-concept based on the answer above:

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_view_pre_view().
 */
function my_module_views_pre_view(ViewExecutable $view, $display_id, array &$args) {
  if ($view->id() == 'news' && isset($args[0])) {
    if ($args[0] == 'video') {
      $args[0] = 'youtube_video';
    }
  }
}
```

The first arg in the path `/news/video` actually just calls the View with `$view_id = 'news'`, so the contextual filter parameters don't start until the second segment in that path, which is `$arg[0]`.

And it's important to check that `$arg[0]` is set before checking its value; otherwise, the `/news` path will throw errors when no filters are passed.

Finally, in my case there's no need to check for a specific `$display_id`, since I want the string substitution to occur for all displays of this particular View.

Other than that, the answer above got it just right.